# Best alternative to integrate flash app into facebook

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook

I have previous experience with AS3, but not so much in web development. now I want to install a game in facebook, but since im very uninformed, i'm having a bad time chossing the best option. I have three alternatives to integrate my flash app in facebook.

Adobe actionscript API: Until now, I tried it and worked for me to log in , get friends, and that kinda of basic. Has a ton of problems and bugs, and i decided to switch.

FMBS seems to be the best option, according to most people feedback in forums, but it's going to be deprecated and i don't want to invert effort and time in an option that is going to be dipossed.

What do i have left ?, iframe ? Javascript ?

Thanks for your orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well iframe can not be best option at least as Facebook suggests try minimizing the use of iframe for Facebook. Better using FBML( Facebook markup language with PHP). 
First, you need to build and setup the basic app.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

To merge your swf in  PHP-based page that is  tag

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/swf